# Как сделать программный RAID 0 на дисках ранее использованных в аппаратном RAID 0 без потери данных?

Tags: windows, raid

Можно ли в Windows 10 сделать программный RAID 0 на дисках ранее использованных в аппаратном RAID 0 без потери данных?
Если да, подскажите мануал.

Comment: В седой древности были программы, которые умели собрать райд из отдельных дисков потухшего контроллера. Не исключено, что и сейчас где-то таковые имеются. Поищи. Тем более что обычно райд-0 ничего особо лишнего на диски не пишет (ну, может, в голове диска какое лишнее немного, максимум на нулевом цилиндре), и вся задача - собрать блоки правильно, что не сильно сложно, особенно если знаешь размер блока. Это с другими уровнями заморока... А вот системный софт этого точно не умеет.

Comment: Видел я однажды в начале такого "простого" рейда-0 длинную индексную таблицу и журнал транзакций.

Comment: Подобный функционал я видел у платных программ восстановления информации. И да - при использовании можно было подключить диски аппаратного рейда. Пример - ПО фирмы R-Tools Technology. Вопрос о перечне поддерживаемых типов, либо производителей следует адресовать разработчикам ПО. Подключать можно было не только накопители, а ещё и снятые образы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не можно. Проблема в том, что железные контроллеры имеют свой формат, который жестко привязан (в общем случае) к конкретной ревизии данного контроллера.

Так что если у вас сдох контроллер, вам нужно найти *идентичный*, слить данные, а потом уже перейти на софтовый рейд.

Comment: Жесть, как не приятно выходит :С

Comment: Не всегда так жёстко. Некоторые производители предоставляют инженерные утилиты, позволяющие восстановить данные с накопителей, одновременно подключенных к другим контроллерам (даже другого производителя). Но всё зависит от уровня обслуживания/поддержки. Для обычного пользователя, увы, боюсь, подобный подход почти невозможен.